# afplayer not run video in 4 inches devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

I have tried to play mp4 video in a background view.. but this code working fine and giving result in simulators and iPhone 6, and 6+
but when I am running this to iPhone 5 or related these screen devices.. video not playing or running..

I am using this code:

```
NSString *filepath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"login" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath1];

vwVideoBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

self.avPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath1]];
//AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] retain];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.avPlayerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
NSLog(@"%@",filepath1);
avPlayerLayer.frame = self.view.frame;
[vwVideoBg.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
//[self.view addSubview:vwVideoBg];

[self.avPlayer play];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Comment: So can you see only black color screen ?

Comment: nothing will be show.. only my content showing

Comment: you set wVideoBg.backgroundColor = black color so it should be show.. right ?

Comment: yes when i set vw background color, and view layer background color it shows color

Comment: Set vwVideoBg frame manualy and see whats happen.

Comment: nothing will be happen.. video not showing